# Podofo word spacing

Tags: c++, podofo

I want to change the word spacing in a PDF text. I use podofo 0.10.0 for that.

If you run the following sample, SetWordSpacing has no effect.

```
 PdfMemDocument document;
 auto& page = document.GetPages().CreatePage(PdfPage::CreateStandardPageSize(PdfPageSize::A4));
 auto font = document.GetFonts().SearchFont("Arial"); 
 
 PdfPainter painter;
 painter.SetCanvas(page);
 painter.TextState.SetFont(*font, 18);
 painter.TextState.**SetWordSpacing**( 10.0 ); 
 painter.DrawText("Hello world text", 56.69, page.GetRect().Height - 56.69);
 painter.FinishDrawing();
 document.Save(filename);
```

How does word spacing work with podofo?